# Vue - how to recognize [__ob__: Observer]?

Tags: vue.js, observers

In my component I loop through a data property, which is an object, to check whether any values are set.
One of the values is an array, but when it's empty and I console log its value  it returns

`[__ob__: Observer]`.

If I test if it's an array or object, it doesn't return true on either of them.
It is only recognized as an array when an element has been added to it.

I also tried to test if it's a function (`entry[1] === "function"`) - not true.

So what is `[__ob__: Observer]` and how can I make a check that recognizes this particular thing? I need to make an exception for it.

Answer (score 2):

VueJS has "reactivity", which means they observe the object for you. So in your basic data option, Vue will watch the properties for you.

```
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      myArray: []
    }
  }
})
```

In this case myArray will be an obeservable object, this is just a wrapper and you can still use all of the standard array manipulations.

That means you can still do:

```
if (this.myArray && this.myArray.length > 0) {
 Do something with they array
}
```

More on how VueJS handles the data option. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is debugging WHAT included in `Observer` Vue instance, this is my solution:

> Print out that variable in `template` block belongs to your Component

After that, you can reformat the structure of the output to observe the detail.

For example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ your_variable }}
  <div>
</template>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to check whether the array is empty, why not just check `arrayVariable.length === 0`?
`[__ob__: Observer]` is an object with Vue-injected reactivity. You can check `typeof arrayVariable` and you should get `object`.

Answer (score 0):

As quoted from [this thread](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-is-the---obv---observer-object/21767):

> {obv:Observer} means your vuex object is null

and:

> That’s a special property added by Vue, it’s part of the Reactivity system which allows Vue to track data changes and react to them:

So basically, it's *nothing*.

In your case, it's just an empty array that's monitored by Vue to react to changes.